# Video not playing in Firefox on server but will play on local development box

Tags: firefox, video

Testing out an updated site with HTML5 and I cannot play video when using Firefox on my hosting server which is running "Windows IIS 8 w/ Plesk on GoDaddy shared".  This updated site will run everything properly on my local development server without any issues in Firefox.  It was suggested that I create a wev.config file.

I created a web.config file containing the following to update mime mapping:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg oga" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm .webm" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
    </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I still cannot get the video to start on the server.  Go Daddy suggested I post this.  The test site URL www.gslproductions.com/zzzdefault.html

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Best Regards,

e

Comment: It seems your site is sending out the video with mimetype `video/mpeg`. If you open up the firefox console, the following message will appear when you load your site `Warning: HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.gslproductions.com/video/Blackberry.mp4 failed.`

Comment: maybe the converted video is not an accurate translation.  I'll re-convert a video file and retest.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually this seems more a issue with [godaddy](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-PT/questions/973142)